# Buddypress - Adding friends breaks layout

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am pretty new to Buddypress (this is my first install) and not so new to WP.  I have a custom theme with Buddypress installed and all works great with the exception of adding/canceling friend requests.  Whenever someone hits Add/Cancel Friend then for some reason it breaks the layout of the page by displaying what looks like a iframe of our site.

I have looked around the forums and google to see if I maybe forgot to add something in my theme but cant get it right.

The only way I have been able to (temporarily) fix this is by display:none on the .pending_friend selector but I know it will still display in the markup and is not the best solution.

Has anyone encountered this yet, or can suggest a fix?  I feel like it is probably something really simple and my over complicated thought process just isnt seeing it.

Attached is a screen shot of what happens when you add/cancel friends??

Help
[image: layout breaks]

Comment: It looks like a user injected an iframe into your admin area. Email the wp security list.

Comment: Well this site is less than a week old and all users are friends just testing it out..  the same thing happens when I place the search bar in the sidebar, which I just fixed by removing the search widget. But I feel like its a matter of declaring something in my functions.php or copying over templates/functions from the BP theme?

Im pretty sure it is not a user issue though, thanks for the help though Denis

Answer (score 0):

Found out the starter theme I was using had deregistered the default version of JQuery to load its own, so after troubleshooting I just removed their call to deregister and enqueue scripts and just let Wordpress do its thing, all is working perfectly now.